# Show that $f(x) = x \cdot |x|^2$ with $|x|<1$ is Lipshitz continuous.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am reading Body & Soul, Part $3$ and got stuck with this exercise:

> Show that $f(x) = x \lvert x\rvert^2$ with $\lvert x\rvert<1$ is Lipschitz continuous, where $x$ is a $3$d vector.

I guess that the Lipschitz constant is one, but am unable to prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $x$ a real variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\lvert x \rvert < 1$ and $\lvert y \rvert < 1$. We have

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \lvert x\lvert x\rvert^2 - x\lvert y\rvert^2 + x\lvert y\rvert^2 - y\lvert y\rvert^2\rvert \le \lvert x\rvert \lvert \lvert x\rvert^2 - \lvert y\rvert^2\rvert + \lvert x - y\rvert \lvert y\rvert^2\tag{*}$$

Now

$$\lvert \lvert x\rvert^2 - \lvert y\rvert^2| = \lvert (\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert)(\lvert x\rvert - \rvert y\rvert)\rvert = (\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert)\lvert \lvert x \rvert - \lvert y\rvert\rvert$$

By the triangle inequality, $\lvert \lvert x\rvert - \lvert y \rvert \rvert \le \lvert x - y \rvert$. Hence

$$\lvert \lvert x\rvert^2 - \lvert y\rvert^2\rvert \le (\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert)\lvert x - y\rvert$$

and so by $(*)$,

$$\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \le \lvert x\rvert (\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y \rvert)\lvert x - y\rvert + \lvert y \rvert^2 \lvert x - y \rvert =  (\lvert x\rvert^2 + \lvert x\rvert \lvert y \rvert + \lvert y \rvert^2)\lvert x - y\rvert$$

Since $\lvert x\rvert < 1$ and $\lvert y \rvert < 1$, then $\lvert x\rvert^2 + \lvert x \rvert \lvert y \rvert + \lvert y \rvert^2 < 3$. Therefore

$$\lvert f(x) - f(y)\lvert < 3\lvert x - y\rvert$$

Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary, $f$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $3$.

Comment: Thanks! I could follow your computation. Well written.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a real variable, $f(x)$ is but $x^3$. Hence you have to show $x^3$  is Lipschitz on $(-1,1)$.

Now use the identity $\;x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ to obtain
$$\lvert x^3-y^3\rvert\le\lvert x-y \rvert(x^2+\lvert xy\rvert+y^2)\le \lvert x-y \rvert(1+1+1).$$
As $3$ is the least upper bound of $x^2+xy+y^2$ on $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$, the function is Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant equal to $3$.

Comment: I don't have the book you mention, and that's why I asked if it's a real variable in a comment, which you didn't answer to. I'll withdraw my answer in a moment.